# Linq to SQL - How to sort results from query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows, linq

I have a LINQ query I am retrieving, although in its context how would I sort the output, I have tried sortby etc. but to no avail

```
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var returnall = from p in db.Orders
                    select p.ShipName;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var returnall = from p in db.Orders
                orderby p.ShipName
                select p.ShipName;
```

A handy reference for various LINQ functions can be found on the [MSDN samples page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746).

Comment: @James: no, it would order it by the `ShipName`, which I assume is a string. You can also order by any other field available in `db.Orders`. FYI, in case you want a descending order, you can also put `orderby p.ShipName descending`

Comment: Addition to your answer: orderby shipname ascending and orderby shipname decending

Comment: you dont have to use "orderby shipname ascending" ... its ordered ascending by default so use just "orderby shipname"

Answer (score 6):

you can use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756#OrderBySimple1) to order the single property for multiple property use [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756#thenBySimple) also

```
 DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
 var returnall = db.OrderBy(r=> r.OrderDelivaryDate).
                    ThenBy(r => r. OrderName);
```

This query will sort first by `OrderDelivaryDate` then by `OrderName`

Here is some simple linq queries http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756#thenBySimple

Answer (score 3):

```
var ret = db.Orders.OrderBy( x => x.ShipName );
```

Answer (score 1):

[order by](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756)

Answer (score 0):

To sort results from query on **one** or **more** fields:

**Data:**

```
        List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>() { new Employee() { emp_id = 101, emp_name = "David", emp_lang = "Java", dpt_id = 1 }
                                                    ,new Employee() { emp_id = 102, emp_name = "Lana",emp_lang = "C#", dpt_id = 2 }
                                                    ,new Employee() { emp_id = 103, emp_name = "Sona",emp_lang = "Java", dpt_id = 3 }
                                                    ,new Employee() { emp_id = 104, emp_name = "Mike",emp_lang = "C++", dpt_id = 3 }
                                                    ,new Employee() { emp_id = 105, emp_name = "Roma",emp_lang = "C#", dpt_id = 1 }
```

**Query:**

```
    var res = from e in emp
              orderby e.emp_lang, e.dpt_id
              select new { e.emp_name, e.emp_lang, e.dpt_id }
```

**Result**:

```
{ emp_name = "Roma", emp_lang = "C#", dpt_id = 1 }
{ emp_name = "Lana", emp_lang = "C#", dpt_id = 2 }
{ emp_name = "Mike", emp_lang = "C++", dpt_id = 3 }
{ emp_name = "David", emp_lang = "Java", dpt_id = 1 }
{ emp_name = "Sona", emp_lang = "Java", dpt_id = 3 }
```